# No possibilities to organize my typescript code and prevent polluting global namespace out of the box?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Now that the modules became namespaces and namespaces became deprecated as you can read [here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-namespace/), do I have any possibilities left to organize my typescript code?

And the main question is, what possibilities do I have to prevent polluting the global namespace? Because in my opinion I have none left and that would be a huge dealbreaker in comparison to vanilla JS.

Comment: Use ES6 modules and a module bundler such as Webpack or Browserify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modules are by far the best way to manage your application. [Modules add zero items to the global scope](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2017/08/stop-mixing-typescript-modules-and-namespaces/), and they provide many different options for loading.

Namespaces are second-best, as they add a single item to the global scope - and if you nest them, you can keep all of your namespaces within a single root meaning no matter how large your application gets, you have just one item in the global scope.

Namespaces have not been deprecated, the TSLint rule is a nudge to push people towards modules - but as with all TSLint rules - *you* are in charge, *not* the tools. If you decide that your architecture will use namespaces, you can switch off the rule with this configuration:

```
"no-namespace": false
```

## Modules, Namespaces, and Bears... oh my!

When TypeScript 0.8 came out, there were "internal modules" and "external modules". These later got renamed, so they changed like this:

1. Internal Modules became "Namespaces"
2. External Modules became "Modules"

For internal modules, it just meant changing:

```
module OrderProcessing {
```

To:

```
namespace OrderProcessing {
```

And for external modules, it just means referring to them as "modules" as you don't wrap external modules with anything. An external module (or "module" as it is now known) is just a file that exports something...

module.ts

```
export function go() {
    return 'go go go';
}
```

You can use a module from another file...

```
import { go } from './module.js';

alert(go());
```

None of the contents of `module.ts` makes it into the global scope.

Neither `namespace` or modules are deprecated, you can use either (but don't mix them). TSLint would rather you used modules.

Comment: But am I right, that we have no possibilities left to prevent polluting global namespace with this rule enabled?

Comment: @FlorianLeitgeb -  you still have modules, which add zero items to the global scope.

Comment: As I understood, modules were renamed to namespace and were deprecated.

Comment: @FlorianLeitgeb - full details of the history of modules added above.

Comment: Thank you! This explanation was exactly I was searching for. But as I understood, nothing that is written in a .ts file will ever make it into the global namespace unless I export it? In fact, every .ts file is automatically module, so nothing that I write in it, will be globally exposed. Is that correct?

Comment: Every .ts file is a module, although it must `export` something to be usable as a module. Nothing hits the global scope at all with modules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159065/discussion-between-florian-leitgeb-and-fenton).

Comment: The [rule detail page](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-namespace/) says: `ES6-style external modules are the standard way to modularize code.` Is this explained somewhere in the TS official documentation?